# Internal-linking of texts out of .csv files (in java)

Tags: java, php, csv

I have a .csv file with text, and am supposed to parse the data, and based on specific keywords, replace the words with the necessary html tags for linking the keywords to a website.

So far, I wrote a .csv parser and writer, that gets all the data from the columns required out of the first file, and prints those columns to a newly created (.csv) file (e.g. text id in one cell, text title in the next cell, and the actual text in the next cell).

Now I am still waiting to get a list of keywords, as well as the website hierarchy and links to put it, but to be honest I have no idea how to continue working on this. Somehow I'll have to parse down the website hierarchy to where the text title is present, and only consider elements beneath it, and link them to keywords in my text. How can this be done? I there special software of extensions, libs, packs for java to do something like this?

Any help would be appreciated, I'm running on a deadline here... 
THX!

P.S.: I am coding all of it in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but it sounds like you want to create an href column in your output:

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com" id="foo" title = "bar">Visit W3Schools</a>
```

You could do this most simply by concatenating the strings:

```
String makeHref(String title, String id, String link) {
    return "<a href=" + ... etc. }
```

before you write out the second csv. You'll need to escape the "s, of course.

It's also entirely possible that I didn't understand the question. You may want to try to be more specific if that's the case.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I just got the list of links, and it basically is just a xlsx files with words an links. Your answer answeres my question, thank you very much!